# Выброс исключения без параметров

Tags: c++, исключения

Читаю статью по исключениям и решил скопировать код оттуда. Вот код:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

try {
    throw;
}
catch (...) {
    cout << "exception\n";
    return 1;
}

cout << "No exeption\n";
return 0;

}
```

В статье написано что блок catch должен поймать его, но этого не происходит. Почему? Использую msvs 2017. И ещё,

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
int x = 0;
try {
    cout << 2 / x;
}
catch (...) {
    cout << "exception\n";
    return 1;
}
```

Тут тоже не ловится исключение типа "Деление на 0". Почему?

Comment: Потому что вы ничего не бросаете.  Попробуйте так throw Exception(); Предварительно надо объявить ранее сlass Exception {}, или взять стандартный из std

Comment: http://www.codenet.ru/progr/cpp/Try-Catch-Throw.php я вот тут статью читаю. Она получается говорит неправду?

Comment: там указано throw 1;

Comment: Не, там ниже код точь-в-точь как я написал

Comment: А ниже написано - *Такой метод может применяться в случаях, когда не нужно передавать никаких данных в блок catch*.

Comment: Да, есть такой вариант. Похоже работает либо как terminate - прерывает выполнения приложения, либо, если находится внутри какого-то catch() то просто перебрасывает исключение дальше (выше по стеку)

Comment: если вы бросили где то исключение (это может быть только обьект), то вы повторно можете бросить исключение в теле  catch. Но у вас не брошено нигде исключение, а попытка бросить его заново

Comment: При делении на ноль поведение не определено.  В данном случае вам надо самому проверять делитель на 0 и бросать исключение при необходимости. Дело в том, что исключения - рукотворные объекты, а не результат работы мозгов компьютера

Comment: Вот список утвержденных исключений (может быть не полный, надо лезть в стандарт)

The exceptions listed in the ISO standard are:

namespace std {
    class logic_error;
        class domain_error;
        class invalid_argument;
        class length_error;
        class out_of_range;
    class runtime_error;
        class range_error;
        class overflow_error;
        class underflow_error;
}

Comment: Вот прямо копия вашего доп.вопроса с ответом: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121623/catching-exception-divide-by-zero

Comment: Деление на ноль не является нормальным для C++, но для MSVC можно включить перехват таких исключений. Это является расширением именно MSVC и не имеет отношения к C++.

Comment: @Сергей Терпеливый: Вся статья - очень низкокачественная и местами содержит полнейшую чушь.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, есть такой вариант.

- Если указан в теле try, то работает как terminate, то есть с "мясом"
  прерывает выполнение текущего приложения (порты и файлы не закрываются, ресурсы не освобождаются).
- Если находится внутри какого-то catch(), то есть мы уже поймали какое-то типизированное исключение, то это просто короткая запись для "перебрасывания"
  того же исключения дальше (выше по стеку).

Comment: Простите, а выше по стеку это как? Я просто не понимаю

Comment: В функцию вызова текущей фукции, если таковая имеется. Например, функция func1 вызвала func2, а в ней брошено исключение, которое там же поймано, обработано и выкинуто далее, то есть в func1, где тоже может быть поймано и обработано, или нет, если нет ловушек, тогда оно полетит еще выше - в операционную систему, которая может поймать, обидеться, что в нее бросаются и закрыть нафиг приложение

Comment: спасибо за ответ

Comment: Я дополнил вопрос новым вопросом, дабы не создавать новую тему.

Comment: "Если указан в теле try..." - это несколько вводящее в заблуждение утверждение. `throw` не обязан быть указан в теле `try`. `throw` может быть указан где угодно, но во время выполнения программы такой `throw` должен вызываться *во время выполнения* какого-то тела `try`. Таким образом один и тот же `throw` может перевыбрасывать исключение, а может вызывать `std::terminate`, в зависимости от того, из какого контекста вызвана содержащая его функция.

Comment: @AnT то есть может быть и вне тела, но во время выполнения должен вызываться в теле try?

Comment: @Alexander Chernin: Да, именно так.

Comment: @AnT а вне тела он просто не вызовится?

Comment: @Alexander Chernin: Не понял. О чем вы? Что значит "не вызовится"? Вам же ясно сказали: если выполнить `throw` тогда, когда нет активного `try {}`, то произойдет `std::terminate`.

Answer (score 9):

Оператор `throw` без параметров может использовать только во время обработки уже пойманного исключения. В остальных случаях попытка выполнения оператора `throw` без параметра приведет к немедленному вызову `std::terminate`.

http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.throw#4

> **4** If no exception is presently being handled, evaluating a throw-expression with no operand calls std​::​​terminate().

Обратите внимание: "во время обработки уже пойманного исключения" - это характеристика *времени выполнения*. То есть такой `throw` не обязан явно синтаксически располагаться на территории `try`-блока. Такой `throw` только должен *выполняться* во время, когда  какой-то `try`-блок активен.

---

В языке С++ нет никакого исключения "деление на 0". Деление на 0 приводит к *неопределенному поведению*, а не к выбросу исключения. Исключения в С++ выбрасываются либо явно, при помощи `throw`, либо неявно изнутри конструкций языка и стандартной библиотеки в специально оговоренных случаях. Деление на 0 таким случаем не является.

Answer (score 8):

`throw` без параметров действительно может быть использован. Он предназначен для того, чтобы *перебросить* исключение в вышестоящий `try-catch` блок.

```
void foo()
{
   throw 10;
}

void buz()
{
   try
   {
      foo();
   }
   catch(...)
   {
      std::cout << "exception in buz()\n";
      throw;
   }
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        buz();
    }
    catch(int er)
    {
        std::cout << "exception in main: " << er << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Если на момент использования `throw;` ни одно исключение не обрабатывается (не является активным), тогда такое выражение будет вызывать `std::terminate`.

[Посмотреть](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YWQ40u8klQvQpMdb)

[throw](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw)

Answer (score 5):

С сайта [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/):

> It is also possible to nest try-catch blocks within more external try blocks. In these cases, we have the possibility that an internal catch block forwards the exception to its external level. This is done with the expression throw; with no arguments. For example:

```
try {
    try {
        // code here
    }
    catch (int n) {
        throw;
    }
}
catch (...) {
    cout << "Exception occurred";
}
```

Т.к. сообщество рускоязычное, суть примерно такая:

*Также возможно вложить try-catch блоки внутрь других внешних блоков. В этих случаях внутренний catch-блок может перенаправить исключение внешнему. Это достигается при помощи выражения `throw;` без аргументов.*

Это подтверждает то, что сказал *AR Hovsepyan* в комментарии под вопросом:

> Но у вас не брошено нигде исключение, а попытка бросить его заново